# Deleting previous contents of CSV file from second row and appending new content in to the same file

Tags: python, csv

Iam data logging the sensor data in a CSV file. I have headings on the first row. I deleted all the content of the CSV file from second row and try to append a new list into CSV file but it is not appending to second row. It is added to first row itself.

i tried the following code now iam getting the output

```
import csv
List = ["16-09 -2021","02:34:07","182","182","183","17","13","18","2046","1514","2179","2610","2047","2931"]

with open('energylog1.csv', mode='a+') as csvfile: # try to delete prevous contents of the file from second row
    csvfile.truncate(45)
    
with open('energylog1.csv', mode='a+') as csvfile: # try to add the List from second row of the csv file
    sensor_write = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    write_to_log = sensor_write.writerow(List)
```

I tried the above code i delete the contents of the CSV file from second row but when i try to append a list in to the file. It is not appending to second row it is added to the first row itself.

[Here is my output][1]

i tried this way its working now

```
List1 = ["Date","Time","Vr","Vy","Vb","Ir","Iy","Ib","Er","Ey","Eb","Pr","Py","Pb"]
List = ["16-09-2021","02:34:07","223","182","183","17","13","18","2046","1514","2179","2610","2047","2931"]

with open('energylog1.csv', mode='a+') as csvfile:
     csvfile.truncate(0)
with open('energylog1.csv', newline='', mode='a') as csvfile:     
     sensor_write = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
     write_to_log = sensor_write.writerow(List1)
     write_to_log = sensor_write.writerow(list)
```

Comment: Try adding a newline before appending?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: i tried this way also  with open('energylog1.csv',newline='',mode='a+')  as csvfile  but i got the same output no change

Comment: A more reliable approach would be to just use `'w'` and rewrite the first (header) row each time.

Comment: As Martin suggested i tried but with a+ itself and i got the output. Thank you